# Vertically align image in 960.gs div?

Tags: css, image, vertical-alignment, 960.gs

I am using 960.gs, and want to vertically align an IMG.  My sense is that
the IMG within the first DIV of grid_3 has no idea as to the height of the
rest of the row (the div of grid_6 suffix_3).  The image hugs the top...

Some constraints: I may not know the height of the image.  I may not know the
height of the content in the DIV to the right.

Without resorting to javascript, what's a good approach that wont break 960.gs?
Is this where I go to a nested container, just so that I can vertically center an
IMG?   I have tried the css rule:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

There's obviously more to it....

```
Snippet...

    <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_3">
                    <img src="images/dlsmug5.png">
            </div>

            <div class="grid_6 suffix_3">
    <h1>My Title - etc...</h1>
    <p>
               Heya, revamp time!  It may not be obvious, but...,
               I am coming up to speed with the CSS framework
               of <a href="http://960.gs">The 960 Grid System</a> ..
    </p>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: AFAIK vertically aligning images using CSS is non-trivial. However, its is independent of 960gs. You can try something along the lines of http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html and see that works out.

Answer (score 3):

You can give to the div a table-cell behavior with a vertical align:

```
.grid_3 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```